# Spark Window - How to compare first row with nth row of a data frame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe as shown below. I have to take the rank of the row that has claim_typ as 'PD' and do a difference with the rank of of the current row and add it as a new column.

Source dataframe:

`Id          svc_dt   clm_typ  rank
48115882    20180209  RV       1
48115882    20180209  RJ       2
48115882    20180216  RJ       3
48115882    20180302  RJ       4
48115882    20180402  PD       5
48115882    20180502  RJ       6`

Expected resultant dataframe:

`Id         svc_dt      clm_typ rank    diff_PD_Rank 
48115882    20180209    RV      1       4   (Current rank - rank of column with 'PD')
48115882    20180209    RJ      2       3 
48115882    20180216    RJ      3       2 
48115882    20180302    RJ      4       1
48115882    20180402    PD      5       null
48115882    20180502    RJ      6       null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PySpark solution.

Assuming there is one row per clm_type 'PD' per id, you can use conditional aggregation with `max(when...))` to get the necessary difference.

```
# necessary imports 
w1 = Window.partitionBy(df.id).orderBy(df.svc_dt)
df = df.withColumn('rnum',row_number().over(w1))
w2 = Window.partitionBy(df.id)
res = df.withColumn('diff_pd_rank',max(when(df.clm_typ == 'PD',df.rnum)).over(w2) - rnum)
res.show()
```

Comment: This worked. I have edited my question and have posted again. Need help.

Comment: that is unfair and invalidates my answer..you should post a new question instead and undo the changes made to the question.

Comment: Am Sorry. Will do it now.

Comment: Hi Vamsi, as you suggested. I have added my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56241454/how-to-find-the-difference-between-1st-row-and-nth-row-of-a-dataframe-based-on-a