# How to find the difference between 1st row and nth row of a dataframe based on a condition using Spark Windowing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, windowing

Here is my exact requirement. I have to add a new column named ("DAYS_TO_NEXT_PD_ENCOUNTER"). As the name indicates, the values in the new column should have a difference of RANK that has claim_typ as 'PD' and the current row. For one ID, it can occur in-between any of the 'RV's and 'RJ's. For the rows that are present after the first occurence of claim_typ as 'PD', the difference should be null as shown below:

The API 'last' works if the clm_typ 'PD' occurs as the last element. It will not be the case always. For one ID, it can occur in-between any of the 'RV's and 'RJ's.

`+----------+--------+---------+----+-------------------------+
|       ID | WEEK_ID|CLAIM_TYP|RANK|DAYS_TO_NEXT_PD_ENCOUNTER|
+----------+--------+---------+----+-------------------------+
|  30641314|20180209|       RV|   1|                        5|
|  30641314|20180209|       RJ|   2|                        4|
|  30641314|20180216|       RJ|   3|                        3|
|  30641314|20180216|       RJ|   4|                        2|
|  30641314|20180216|       RJ|   5|                        1|
|  30641314|20180216|       PD|   6|                        0|
|  48115882|20180209|       RV|   1|                        3|
|  48115882|20180209|       RV|   2|                        2|
|  48115882|20180209|       RV|   3|                        1|
|  48115882|20180209|       PD|   4|                        0|
|  48115882|20180216|       RJ|   5|                     null|
|  48115882|20180302|       RJ|   6|                     null|
+----------+--------+---------+----+-------------------------+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shown here is a PySpark solution.

You can use conditional aggregation with `max(when...))` to get the necessary difference of ranks with the first 'PD' row. After getting the difference, use a `when...` to `null` out rows with negative ranks as they all occur after the first 'PD' row.

```
# necessary imports 
w1 = Window.partitionBy(df.id).orderBy(df.svc_dt)
df = df.withColumn('rnum',row_number().over(w1))
w2 = Window.partitionBy(df.id)
res = df.withColumn('diff_pd_rank',max(when(df.clm_typ == 'PD',df.rnum)).over(w2) - rnum)
res = res.withColumn('days_to_next_pd_encounter',when(res.diff_pd_rank >= 0,res.diff_pd_rank))
res.show()
```